# Magento 2: Remove product from cart when a cart according to cart price rule

Tags: magento2, shopping-cart-price-rules

I have created an extension which does this: A free product is added to cart when a cart price rule is applied.

I want to remove the product when the condition becomes false.
Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: did you get any answer ?